# phpQuery. How to parse every ninth <tr> in <td> table tag

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, phpquery

How to parse every ninth  in  table tag, using phpQuery?
I try like this:

> ```
> require ('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
> $url = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/filter/parser.html');
> $document = phpQuery::newDocument($url);
> $table=array();
> foreach ($document->find('tr') as $tr){
>    $users = $tr->find('td,9')->text();
> $table[$users]=true;
> }
> ```

But it's does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:eq()` selector:

```
$tr->find('td:eq(8)')->text()
```

or `.eq()`:

```
$tr->find('td').eq(8)->text()
```

or `nth-child`

```
$tr->find('td:nth-child(9n)')->text()
```